# Loading weights through checkpoint keras provides different results

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, checkpoint

I'm new with keras. In fact, I conceive an autoencoder and train it on a part of Diabetes Dataset. Then, I use keras checkpointer to save the weights so that I can load it later in order to acheive some operations on encoded data vector (calculating the mean of encoded data to extract a class representation)

**The problem**

when I load the weights and then get the encoded data, I got different results each time I run the code. I turn the `compile` and `fit` statements into commentetd state after training the autoencoder to do not repeat the training process each time I run the code.

Here is the code :

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="weights.best.h5",
                               verbose=0,
                               save_best_only=True,
                               save_weights_only=True)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder',
                          histogram_freq=0,
                          write_graph=True,
                          write_images=True)
input_enc = Input(shape=(input_size,))
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_size1, activation='relu')(input_enc)
hidden_11 = Dense(hidden_size2, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
code = Dense(code_size, activation='relu')(hidden_11)
hidden_22 = Dense(hidden_size2, activation='relu')(code)
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_size1, activation='relu')(hidden_22)
output_enc = Dense(input_size, activation='tanh')(hidden_2)
autoencoder_yes = Model(input_enc, output_enc)


autoencoder_yes.compile(optimizer='adam',
                         loss='mean_squared_error', 
                         metrics=['accuracy'])
history_yes = autoencoder_yes.fit(df_noyau_norm_y, df_noyau_norm_y,
                               epochs=200,
                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                shuffle = True,
                                validation_data=(df_test_norm_y, df_test_norm_y),
                                verbose=1, 
                                callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]).history

autoencoder_yes.save_weights("weights.best.h5")
autoencoder_yes.load_weights("weights.best.h5")

encoder_yes = Model (inputs = input_enc,outputs = code)
encoded_input = Input(shape=(code_size, ))
encoded_data_yes = encoder_yes.predict(df_noyau_norm_y)
print(encoded_data_yes.tolist())

X_YES= sum(encoded_data_yes) / 7412
print (X_YES)
```

Anybody can help me find out the reason and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saving the weights even when compile and fit are commented? That would probably overwrite the weights you got from training.

Comment: You are right, that was the reason. When I comment the saving line of the weights the result dosen't change anymore !